# Changing values ​inside row where certain conditions are met in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Changing the -1 values ​​in the industry column of those who write elektrik ve elektronik mühendisliği in the fields_of_study column with another value

[image]

I want to change it like this but I couldn't.

```py
resultdf.loc[resultdf['fields_of_study'] == "Elektrik ve Elektronik Mühendisliği",resultdf["industry"]=="-1"] = "Defense & Space"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach should change the value.

```py
resultdf.loc[(resultdf['fields_of_study'] == "Elektrik ve Elektronik Mühendisliği")
                & (resultdf["industry"]=="-1"), 'industry'] = "Defense & Space"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`pd.Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html)

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# for repeatability
np.random.seed(0)

# fake data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "fields_of_study": np.random.choice(["Elektrik ve Elektronik Mühendisliği", None],
                                        size=(15,)),
    "industry": np.random.choice(["-1", None],
                                 size=(15,))
})

print(df)
```

```
                        fields_of_study industry
0   Elektrik ve Elektronik Mühendisliği       -1
1                                  None       -1
2                                  None       -1
3   Elektrik ve Elektronik Mühendisliği       -1
4                                  None     None
5                                  None       -1
6                                  None     None
7                                  None     None
8                                  None       -1
9                                  None       -1
10                                 None     None
11  Elektrik ve Elektronik Mühendisliği     None
12  Elektrik ve Elektronik Mühendisliği     None
13                                 None     None
14  Elektrik ve Elektronik Mühendisliği       -1
```

```py
# using `.mask`
df["industry"] = df.industry.mask(df.fields_of_study.eq("Elektrik ve Elektronik Mühendisliği")
                                  & df.industry.eq("-1"),
                                  other="Defense & Space")

print(df)
```

```
                        fields_of_study         industry
0   Elektrik ve Elektronik Mühendisliği  Defense & Space
1                                  None               -1
2                                  None               -1
3   Elektrik ve Elektronik Mühendisliği  Defense & Space
4                                  None             None
5                                  None               -1
6                                  None             None
7                                  None             None
8                                  None               -1
9                                  None               -1
10                                 None             None
11  Elektrik ve Elektronik Mühendisliği             None
12  Elektrik ve Elektronik Mühendisliği             None
13                                 None             None
14  Elektrik ve Elektronik Mühendisliği  Defense & Space
```